# How to upgrade to Drupal 9 using DDEV

Tags: ddev, drupal-9

The instructions at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/cli-usage/#drupal-9-quickstart clearly state how to set up a Drupal 9 project.

However, what is the procedure to upgrade an up to date Drupal 8 project to Drupal 9 in DDEV?

We're assuming the "project-type" needs changing, perhaps PHP and DB versions, etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not start a new project with Drupal 9 and inspect the configuration for differences? Do you even need to update anything related to ddev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the D8->D9 upgrade is doing [Drupal things](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later).

For ddev you'll want to

```sh
ddev config --project-type=drupal9
ddev config --mariadb-version=10.3
```

That should be it. The reality is the drupal8 and drupal9 project types behave the same, so that doesn't much matter. But Drupal9 does require MariaDB 10.3, and you might have 10.2 if the project has been around for a long time.

Although you probably aren't forced to change the php version, it would be best to move along to PHP 7.4 at this point if you're not using that. `ddev config --php-version=7.4`